# Cannot upgrade to jhipster 5.3.4

Tags: jhipster

After "yarn global upgrade generator-jhipster", the version is 4.14.5 instead of latest version 5.3.4. why?

My node version is 8.11.1, yarn is 1.3.2.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

2 possibilities:

- when you run `jhipster --version` it prints local version (from local node_modules folder) if your are in a generated project, this enables projects to isolate from each others. In this case you must upgrade the project with `jhipster upgrade`
- when you are not in a generated project, `jhipster --version` prints globally installed version and it probably means that you have installed jhipster twice (once with yarn and once with npm)

Usually the fix to double global installation is to uninstall from npm and yarn then reinstall with one or the other:

## Remove from both yarn and npm

```
yarn global remove generator-jhipster
npm uninstall -g generator-jhipster
```

## Install with just npm

```
npm install -g generator-jhipster
```

Since [JHipster 5.3.0](https://www.jhipster.tech/2018/09/03/jhipster-release-5.3.0.html) npm is now the default client package manager, instead of Yarn.

## Check version

```
jhipster --version
Using JHipster version installed globally
5.3.4
```

Comment: Hi Gaël, I uninstall both yarn and npm and when I ask for the version, it says jhipster is not recognized, Perfect. Then, I install with npm and when i ask for the version it says: INFO! Using JHipster version installed locally in current project's node_modules 4.14.3 (but the install was a global one: npm install -g generator-jhipster). It doesn't look like it is correctly installed. Thanks

Comment: Hi Mike, I can only suggest you to look at how your PATH is defined and search for jhipster or jhipster.cmd, read the code of the jhipster command it's easy and you'll understand how it works. Use `which jhipster` on linux or OSX and `whereis jhispter`on Windows if you have a doubt where it is lcoated.

Answer (score 1):

Right tick answer didn't work for me, which describe following steps:

1. yarn global remove generator-jhipster
2. npm uninstall -g generator-jhipster
3. npm install -g generator-jhipster

In my case I removed all mode modules & node itself, then fresh installation of jhipster worked for me.