# Yarn & Npm for Jhipster

Tags: jhipster

I somehow have both yarn and npm for JHipster on my Linux Mint laptop. After I do the followings

```
yarn global remove generator-jhipster
yarn global add generator-jhipster
```

There isn't a result for

```
which jhispter
```

After I run the following commands

```
npm uninstall -g generator-jhipster
npm install -g generator-jhipster
```

an old version Jhipster shows up for

```
which jhispter
```

I have done an online search on the subject, but unable to resolve this problem after trying some methods mentioned on some posts.

How to get it right?

Comment: It looks like you are installing with both npm and yarn.  Try https://stackoverflow.com/a/52491140/3737815

Comment: The process mentioned in the post is necessarily the same as I mentioned above. The Jhipster version I get is 5.2.1 by following the steps. I notice that "Using JHipster version installed locally in current project's nod_modules" which is different from the post: local vs global. Also, the installation is on "/usr/bin/lib/mode_modules/generator-jhipster/cli/jhipster.js"

Comment: The steps you listed install with yarn, then install with npm (only use one or the other).  You also might be confusing local node_modules vs global node_modules, your JHipster project installs the version it was generated with and will use that version unless you update the version in package.json and install a newer version (with just `npm install` in your project)

Comment: I followed the steps mentioned by Gael on the post. I only installed JHIpster with npm. If npm is perfectible, why the generator mentions using a yarn command to update?

Comment: Neither "yarn global upgrade generator-jhiper " or "npm update -g generator-jhipster" can get my Jhipster upgraded.

Comment: Are you running `jhipster` from your project, and if so did you check the version defined in your package.json?

Comment: What is the output of `which jhipster`? Path ? Did you ever use npm link or yarn link?

Comment: @JonRuddell The JHipster version is in the 5.2.1 which is correct for the local module.

Comment: @GaëlMarziou The path is /usr/bin/jhipster and I haven't use either npm link nor yarn link.

Comment: Have you tried to run it under debugger with `node inspect /usr/bin/jhipster` ?

Comment: @GaëlMarziou As I mentioned early, /usr/bin/jhipster is linked to "/usr/bin/lib/mode_modules/generator-jhipster/cli/jhipster.js. I don't know what I shall expect from node inspect ... I can't find any helpful information on https://nodejs.org/en/docs/guides/debugging-getting-started/

Comment: Stepping and inspecting variables, see https://nodejs.org/api/debugger.html `node inspect`is different from `node --inspect`. Why don't you try?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/180757/discussion-between-vic-and-gael-marziou).

Comment: You can run `which jhipster` to know the path of the script you are executing but I would strongly advise installing only with npm or yarn and not mixing both as it can get really confusing.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When confused about your local setup after installing JHipster through many ways (npm, yarn, linking from the sources, ...), I have found a way that works all the time. Recent version of NodeJs come with a useful tool called npx which can download a package from npm and execute it immediately. So the trick is simply to run:

`npx generator-jhipster`

You can also run a specific version, for example:

`npx generator-jhipster@v5.3.4`

Comment: Thanks for the tip. I try it and find out the command will run Jhipster latest version, but won't change the JHipster installation to the latest version.

Comment: Yes that's exactly what it does but don't worry because when running the jhipster cli in the application folder, jhipster will execute from the node_module folder so it will always be the right version.

Comment: Thanks for the tip! I had many different verison of jhipster installed in different location and tried to removed them without success. this command allowed me to regenerate my entity with the right version everytime.
npx generator-jhipster@4.14.5 entity Article